# node.js external libraries in webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I noticed that webstorm has an external libraries node in the project explorer.  In that I see Node.js 0.6.15 and also an option for Node.js Globals.

Two questions:

1. Can I have it reference node 0.8?
2. What is Node.js Globals for?

Are the external libraries used for code completion?

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html and http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/node-js-2.html.

Comment: Cool, that second link did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is configured as a Global Library in WebStorm. If you want to use another version, delete the existing library and [follow the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/node-js-2.html) to configure the new version, during the configuration process a new global library will be added.

It's used for code completion and stepping in debug mode.